# $stateProvider redirect instead of transition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm having a hard time configuring `$stateProvider` to just redirect (like `$routeProvider` does) instead of transitioning to a given url.

I've got some root url's where I don't want the transition to happend.
Like going from `/home` to `/about`. But I do want a transition between `/about` and `/about/team` where `/team` is a subpage of `/about`.

I can't find any help for this on the official docs.

app.coffee

```
.config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->
    $stateProvider
        .state( "news",
            url: '/news'
            controller: "NewsCtrl"
            templateUrl: "templates/news.html"
        )
        .state( "about",
            url: '/about'
            controller: "AboutCtrl"
            templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
        )
        .state( "about.team",
            url: '/team'
            views:
                "@":
                    controller: "AboutTeamCtrl"
                    templateUrl: "templates/about.team.html"
        )
```

Comment: I think it would be best if you posted more code, like that in your route config.

Comment: What do you mean by not wanting the transition to happen between root urls?

Comment: Please explain the difference in behavior you're asking for in wanting a redirect instead of a transition.